# Using a Scavenger Bird Ki Focus

Tags: dnd-4e, assassin

I recently picked up the [Scavenger Bird Ki Focus](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=7829) for my assassin. Does the ki focus' enhancement bonus to attack and damage rolls get applied to any weapon that I am wielding?

Also, when I use its at-will power, does only the number of shrouds you have on the enemy move to a new enemy?

Just want to make sure I'm reading it right.

Comment: So is this saying that you use your shrouds and then transfer them.  Because if so, that makes the assassin unbelievably powerful...

Comment: @Denns - Wecome to the site.  Your query here is more of a "comment" than it is an "answer" to this question.  I've flagged it for a diamond moderator to move accordingly.  However, it would probably be even better if you could flesh this out and post it as a separate question entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the implement enhancement is applied to any weapon you're using. If you're using a magic weapon, you choose between the implement enhancement and the weapon enhancement before you roll to hit. You only get the effects and powers for the one you use -- so if you used a weapon enhancement bonus instead of the Scavenger Bird enhancement bonus, you wouldn't get the extra shroud damage on a critical hit.

As far as the power goes, you're correct: every shroud on the enemy you hit moves to a new enemy. If you somehow had shrouds on that enemy already (which I think is impossible currently), you couldn't go above the normal limit of four shrouds.

Comment: Bryant is dead-on as usual, though the interaction between Ki Focus benefits and Magic Weapon benefits still continues to boggle me somewhat.

As far as I know, there is no way currently existing for one to have shrouds on multiple targets at once.

"The shrouds last until you use this power against a different enemy or until the end of the encounter."

This means that, if you were to use Assassin's Shroud against the second enemy before using the Scavenger Bird Ki Focus' power, then there would no longer be any shrouds on the first enemy for you to transfer over.

Comment: Me too. I was tangentially a bit surprised that the Essentials assassin retains the same mechanic, but there you go.